# Rasterising text automatically

Tags: macos, graphics, text

I'm working on a typeface, and am looking at generating test-cases of how specific strings are rendered. What's the simplest way of automatically rasterising many different text-files into a bitmap?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  You might need to elaborate a bit. This could be as simple as taking jpeg/png pictures of TextEdit with Automator.

Comment: I didn't know about Automator; I'll try that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a html header with font selection (by mean of cp and >>) and then usewkhtmltoimage (https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to generate images from that. Alternatively, look at the source code and write some 20 lines of Qt code using the same approach.

Proof of concept in PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.setWindowTitle('Textbox to image')
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setFamily("Herculanum")
font.setBold(True)
textbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(w)
textbox.setFont(font)
textbox.resize(280, 40)
textbox.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr")
textbox.grab().save("image.png")
```

Result (png):

[image]

That, with custom distortion is how I actually created a large ML dataset for OCR from custom fonts.

Comment: Great idea, but I ran into [what looks like a wkhtmltopdf bug](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3749). I'll try looking at hacking some C++ next.

Comment: Try pyqt maybe :P

Comment: I ended up using QPainter::drawText onto a QImage. Didn't think to use QTextEdit.

Comment: Or that way, exactly - it's a bit slower when you do it on scale, but that's not really relevant in most cases.